# Rust in stainless steel?

Tags: steel, rust-removal, rust, stainless

The screw eyes in the pic are stainless steel. The wire rope is galvanized steel *supposedly*.

As you can see, the screw eyes have brown where it touches the corroding wire rope.

does the screw eyes have rust or is is something I can clean once I replace the wire rope with stainless wire rope?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The screw eyes are not rusting. That's staining from the steel rope which i doubt is galvanized. The rust stains will come off with a little emery paper rub.

Answer (score 4):

The rust on the stainless eye came from the steel rope. The zinc galvanizing on the wire rope has corroded away leaving bare steel to rust. Using a stainless wire rope will greatly improve the corrosion resistance of the combination and you should have no problem. The eye is probably 316 SS ( 18 -8 + 2% Mo) as are many small consumer fasteners. In a mild environment stainless rope should be fairly rust free . Over time some light rust may develop in the crevice between the rope and eye. Other alloys like 302 SS or 410 SS ( 13 Cr) will be similar . In a sea coast atmosphere all these alloys will rust. So the environment is the dominating factor for the various SS.  ( Assuming the eye is not some ringer like Monel).